# Create a loop with dates

Tags: r, loops, date

I'm working in a data set like this:

```
      date         time      solar
1  2019-05-17    11:20:00   710
2  2019-05-17    11:25:00   712
3  2019-05-17    11:30:00   787
.
.
.
70 2019-08-06    10:20:00   926
71 2019-08-06    10:25:00   204
72 2019-08-06    10:30:00   498
.
.
.
90 2020-01-17    10:20:00   936
91 2020-01-17    10:25:00   639
92 2020-01-17    10:30:00   876
```

In the first column I have date, from every day since 2019-05-17 until 2021-09-10, and I want to create a new data set for every month for example I want a new data set that have all the same data but only for January 2020, and repeat this for every month... I was working in this way:

With the `library(tibbletime)` first I convert my data frame(df1) into:

```
df_t<- as_tbl_time(df1, index = date)
```

Then with:

```
may19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-05')
jun19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-06')
jul19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-07')
ago19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-08')
sep19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-09')
oct19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-10')
nov19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-11')
dic19 <- filter_time(df_t, ~'2019-12')
```

Creates a new data set where I filter df_t with only the info of the month I want, the problem is that I do this for every month since 2019 to 2021, and I would want to do it in an easier way, with a loop for example, the problem is that I don't know how, because if I do the loop I can't put the i in the: '2019-i' because it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use dplyr to group your data frame by a combination of year & month and then split the groups so you then have a list of dataframes/tibbles, one for each month. Something like this...

First I'll just load two packages and create some dummy data:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dates <- seq(ymd("2015-12-01"), ymd("2021-12-01"), by = "days")

df <- tibble(date = dates,
             value = rnorm(length(dates)))
```

Next I create the month/year columns and use them to split the dataframe:

```
month_list <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(date),
         year = year(date),
         month = month(date)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  group_split()
```

Depending on how your date column is set up already `as_date()` should work, or it might not be necessary.

This will give you a list of tibbles, each one for a specific month. You can access them individually by indexing, e.g. `month_list[[1]]`

You might want to assign the month-year combination to the 'name' of each element of the list. This will make it much easier to access the specific month you want (similar to how you were naming your individual dfs as 'Dec19', 'Jan20' etc). Here I iterate over the list and pull out the first values from the month and year column in the dataframe and set it as the name of that element:

```
names(month_list) <- lapply(month_list, function(x){

   m <- x$month[1]
   y <- x$year[1]

   name <- paste(m,y, sep = "-")

   return(name)

})
```

This will allow you to access the appropriate dataframe by referencing the month-year, like so:

```
month_list["1-2016"]
```

or

```
month_list$`1-2016`
```

Hope this helps!